# PHP Docblock for child using parent constructor?

Tags: php, documentation, parent, phpdoc, docblocks

What is the proper way to docblock this?

```
class B extends A
{
    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * One of these, or???
     * @uses A::__construct()
     * @see  A::__construct()
     *
     * @param int|null $id
     * @param []|null  $data
     */
    function __construct($id = null, $data = null)
    {
        parent::__construct($id);

        if ($data) {
            $this->setAll($data);
        }
    }
}
```

I couldn't find any documentation saying that `parent` is a valid keyword. `self` doesn't really make sense either. Do I put both the `@uses` and `@see` tags?

Comment: you would use `@use` if there is a two way communication between the classes and you would set the other class to have `@used-by` tag, if its a one way street you would use `@see`.

Comment: @cmorrissey That makes sense. I guess I would use the `@use` tag then, since the parent constructor is being used by the child.